# Что делать с неисправимыми ошибками секторов?

Tags: железо, hdd, диск

В smart жесткого диска появилось ухудшение параметра Uncorrectable Sector Count предоставляю скриншоты в aida64,CrystalDiskInfo,victoria.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать, это уже он сыпется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Hbw.jpg)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сделал тесты Victoria 3.5 из под DOS, HDD regenerator v2011 и Data Lifeguard Diagnostic for Windows из Windows вот скрины:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю в программе Data Lifeguard Diagnostic for Windows смарт нормальный и тесты тоже. Ничего не понял, получил разные значения тестов и как его понять, что с жестким диском?
И еще смарт в Data Lifeguard Diagnostic for Windows вообще отличается от других.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сравните с каким-нибудь другим компом.

Comment: Не имею возможности протестировать на другом железе

Comment: Второй скриншот из программы victoria? Полный тест в ней делали? Можете также скачать фирменную программу диагностики от производителя жесткого диска и запустить в ней полный тест. Вывод о выходе диска из строя обычно делают, основываясь на показаниях нескольких разных программ.

Comment: Да тест делал сектора что менее 1,5 секунд нашло но их не восстановило. проверял также hdd regenerator v1.71 нашел 14 delays sector

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду **более** 1.5 с, то да, жесткий диск выходит из строя и нужно думать о его замене.

Answer (score 1):

Параметр S.M.A.R.T. "Uncorrectable sectors count" показывает число секторов, при чтении/записи которых произошла неисправимая ошибка и которые были добавлены прошивкой диска в очередь на переназначение. Обычно, после полной проверки диска в Victoria с включенной опцией "Remap" его значение должно стать равным нулю и при этом сектора в очереди будут либо помечены как нормальные (если ошибка была случайностью), либо признаны поврежденными и переназначены (увеличится значение параметра "Reallocated sectors count").

Ненулевое значение параметра, само по себе, не свидетельствует однозначно о выходе жесткого диска из строя, но является одним из признаков этого. Например, [Acronis](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9264) присваивает ему вес 2 при определении ухудшения здоровья жесткого диска. Если это число постоянно растет или помимо него полная проверка диска показывает много поврежденных или медленно читаемых секторов, с высокой вероятностью диск выходит из строя и его нужно заменять. Для принятия конечного решения о признании диска негодным желательно провести полную проверку в нескольких программах, включая фирменную утилиту производителя - например [Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=3) для дисков WD.

Comment: делал remap у Victoria сектора что менее 1,5 секунд и 500мс нашло но их не восстановило. проверял также hdd regenerator v1.71 нашел 14 delays sector

Comment: А да и ще Victoria запускать из под dos или windows?

Comment: @user221117 если проверка нормально работает и выявляет поврежденные сектора в Windows, нет смысла возится с DOS. Вряд ли результат в нем будет чем-то отличаться и он сможет восстановить то, что не восстановилось в Windows.

Comment: Ну а если ее запустить из под Windows и она будет на том hdd который проверяется это нормально?

Comment: @user221117 Это нормально, в том смысле, что диск будет корректно проверен, и числу поврежденных секторов можно верить. Если цель - не только проверить, а также попытаться сделать remap, скорее всего да, для активного системного диска это не сработает. Но это на самом деле не важно, так как remap будет сделан автоматически при попытке записи в один из таких секторов даже при обычной работе диска, без проверки.

Comment: Ясно, а если запустить Victoria 3.51 freeware из под dos с флешки, то какой метод сканирования выбрать линейное чтение или baterflay чтения и способ remap: classic или advance?

Comment: И еще существует версия Victoria 4.7 загрузочная?

Comment: @user221117 На большинство вопросов не могу ответить. Я обычно проверяю из-под Windows, подключая проверяемый диск вторым, с досовской викторией не работал. По поводу advanced remap - он отличается, насколько я знаю, тем что делает 10 попыток вместо одной. Т.е. он может помочь в случае плохо читаемых секторов, но не в случае полностью поврежденных.

Comment: Тесты сделал но результаты совершенно разные

Comment: @user221117 Ну, раз у вас всего лишь 5 секторов >500 мс и утилитой от WD проходит тест, все не так плохо. Некоторое время жесткий диск еще поработает. Если других проблем, вроде медленного чтения или возникающих при копировании файлов ошибок CRC нет, можете пока им пользоваться. Что касается разных результатов, это нормально. Если бы все программы проверяли одинаково, я бы и не рекомендовал проверять в нескольких.

Answer (score 0):

С6 Offline Uncorrectable Sector Count - кол-во нескорректированных ошибок, то есть серьёзное повреждение поверхности диска. Появляются такие ошибки когда заканчивается место в резервной зоне диска для переназначения секторов. Так же могут появляться при резком отключении питания в момент когда диск записывает данные - это так называемые "программные бэд блоки". Если их количество один два, а остальные параметры касающиеся поверхности диска в норме то беспокоиться не стоит. Если же велико, то данные надо спасать
http://fobosworld.ru/jelezo/tehnologii/54-smart-tehnologiy
Значит hdd таки нужно менять, 2 года всего проработал.